# Enforce MapBox Geocoding API to return only results with a zipcode

Tags: api, autocomplete, frontend, mapbox, zipcode

I'm working with [MapBox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#forward-geocoding) to have suggestions of addresses in the location search feature of my website.

The following is a sample call:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Zur.json?country=ch&limit=5&proximity=8.765.432&language=en-GB&access_token=***
```

My goal is to enforce the api to return only results that include a zipcode.

For example if I input "Zur" (limiting the search to Swiss) I get the following:

```
 - Zürich, Zürich, Switzerland
 - Zürich, Switzerland
 - Zürich Airport, Flughafenstrasse, Kloten, Zürich 8302, Switzerland
 - Zurich, Buchs, Zürich 8107, Switzerland
```

The expected results should be without the first two lines, as they don't have a zipcode.

I tried implementing myself the removal of results without the zipcode on client side (just after I got an answer from the api), but it is a suboptimal solution (for example it doesn't ensure to have enough results).

I was not able to find such feature in MapBox. Is there a better solution out of there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add *?types=address*

See all list of types:
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#data-types

Comment: Thank you! I works perfectly for my use case